# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function sendRegistrationErrorNotification()

Tags: php, wordpress

a form I implemented months ago on wordpress has stopped working and is throwing a 500 err in the console when pressing submit (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ())
, and this is the full debug.log as well as code. I am not well versed in full php programming and i am completely at my wits end on how to solve this. any help would be appreciated. removed url names for my own sanity. thank you in advance :)

```
    PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$token in /nas/content/live/r/wp-edacted/content/themes/redacted/function-partials/gravity-forms-hooks-functions.php on line 62 21-Oct-2020 20:26:18 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function sendRegistrationErrorNotification(), 1 passed in /nas/content/live/redacted/wp-content/themes/redacted/function-partials/gravity-forms-hooks-functions.php on line 224 and exactly 3 expected in /nas/content/live/redacted/wp-content/themes/redacted/function-partials/gravity-forms-hooks-functions.php:70
Stack trace:
#0 /nas/content/live/redacted/wp-content/themes/redacted/function-partials/gravity-forms-hooks-functions.php(224): sendRegistrationErrorNotification('{"errors":["You...')
#1 /nas/content/live/redacted/wp-content/themes/redacted/function-partials/gravity-forms-hooks-functions.php(20): submitNewClientRegistration(Array)
#2 /nas/content/live/gredacted/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(289): post_to_third_party(Array, Array)
#3 /nas/content/live/redacted/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#4 /nas/content/live/redacted/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#5 /nas/co in /nas/content/live/gredacted/wp-content/themesredacted/function-partials/gravity-forms-hooks-functions.php on line 70
```

This is the code file:

```
<?php

/*------------------------------------*\
  Submit form entry data to third party
\*------------------------------------*/

add_action( 'gform_after_submission_7', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {
  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 1 $entry: ' . print_r($entry, true));
  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 2 $form: '. print_r($form, true));

  if (rgar($entry, 85) == 'renewal') {
    GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 3 renewal');
    $clientId = rgar($entry, 86);
    $client = queryClientListForAmpleId($clientId);
    $registrationId = $client->active_registration_id;
    submitClientRegistrationRenewal($entry, $registrationId);
  } else {
    GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 3 new registration');
    submitNewClientRegistration($entry);
  }

}

/*------------------------------------*\
  End Submit form entry data to third party
\*------------------------------------*/

/*------------------------------------*\
  Get token from third party
\*------------------------------------*/

function getAmpleToken() {
  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 1');

  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://removedforpriacy:3000/v2/login?username=".AMPLEU."&password=".AMPLEP,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "Accept: application/json",
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ),
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);

  curl_close($curl);

  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 2 $response ' . print_r($response, true));
  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 3 $err ' . print_r($err, true));
  if ($err) {
    error_log('error generating Ample login endpoint token with error : ' . $err);
  } else {
    return json_decode($response)->token;
  }
}

/*----------------------------*\
  End get token from third party
\*----------------------------*/

function sendRegistrationErrorNotification($error, $form, $entry) {
  $emails = get_field('ample_registration_failure_emails', 'option');
  $toAddresses = array();

  foreach ($emails as $email) {
    array_push($toAddresses, $email['ample_registration_failure_email_address']);
  }

  $subject = "redacted for privacy";
  $message = "redacted for privacy";
  $message .= '<br><br>';
  $message .= 'All the submission information is still located within the WordPress backend at the link below.';
  $message .= '<br><br>';
  $message .= get_site_url()."/wp-admin/admin.php?page=gf_entries&view=entry&id=".$form['id']."&lid=".$entry['id']."&order=ASC&filter&paged=1&pos=0&field_id&operator";
  $message .= '<br><br>';
  $message .= 'For Debugging Purposes - The error returned from the Ample API was:';
  $message .= '<br><br>';
  $message .= 'Error: ';
  $message .= $error;  

  add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );

  wp_mail( $toAddresses, $subject, $message );

  remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );
}








function gravity_pdf_download_func( $atts ) {
  $entryID = $atts['entry'];
  $pdfID = $atts['pdf'];
  $text = $atts['text'];

  $pdfURL = get_site_url() . '/pdf/' . $pdfID . '/' . $entryID . '/download';

  return "<a href='".wp_login_url( $pdfURL )."'>" . $text . "</a>";
}
add_shortcode( 'pdfdownload', 'gravity_pdf_download_func' );


// Validation to check client ID against ample API if renewal selected
add_filter( 'gform_validation_7', 'registration_form_custom_validation' );
function registration_form_custom_validation( $validation_result ) {
    $form = $validation_result['form'];

    if ( rgpost( 'input_85' ) == 'renewal' ) {

        $foundClientResult = queryClientListForAmpleId(rgpost('input_86'));

        if (empty($foundClientResult)) {
          $validation_result['is_valid'] = false;
          // //finding Field with ID of 86 and marking it as failed validation
          foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
              if ( $field->id == '86' ) {
                  $field->failed_validation = true;
                  $field->validation_message = 'Ample client ID not found.';
                  break;
              }
          }
        }
    }

    //Assign modified $form object back to the validation result
    $validation_result['form'] = $form;
    return $validation_result;

}

function queryClientListForAmpleId($clientId) {
  $curl = curl_init();

  $token = getAmpleToken();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://redacted/v2/clients?per_page=10000&token=" . $token,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "Accept: application/json",
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ),
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);

  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 1 $response: ' . print_r($response, true));
  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 2 $err: '. print_r($err, true));

  curl_close($curl);

  $foundClientResult = null;


  if ($err) {
    error_log('error hitting client list endpoint with error : ' . $err);
  } else {
    $results = json_decode($response)[1];
    foreach ($results as $result) {
      if ($result->client_id == $clientId) {
        $foundClientResult = $result;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 3 $foundClientResult: '. print_r($foundClientResult, true));

  return $foundClientResult;
}

function submitNewClientRegistration($entry) {
  $values = getApiRegistrationPayloadFromEntry($entry);
  $curl = curl_init();

  $token = getAmpleToken();
  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 1 $token: ' . print_r($token, true));

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://ample.redacted.ca:3000/v2/clients?token=" . $token,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($values),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "Accept: application/json",
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ),
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);
  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 2 $response: ' . print_r($response, true));
  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 3 $err: ' . print_r($err, true));

  curl_close($curl);

  if ($err) {
    sendRegistrationErrorNotification($err);
  } else {
    if (isset(json_decode($response)->error_code)) {
      sendRegistrationErrorNotification($response);
    }
  }
}

function submitClientRegistrationRenewal($entry, $registrationId) {
  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 1 $entry: ' . print_r($entry, true));
  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 2 $registrationId: ' . print_r($registrationId, true));

  $values = getApiRegistrationPayloadFromEntry($entry, true);
  $curl = curl_init();

  $token = getAmpleToken();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://ample.redacted.ca:3000/v2/registrations/".$registrationId."?token=" . $token,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($values),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "Accept: application/json",
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ),
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);

  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 3 $response: ' . print_r($response, true));
  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 4 $err: ' . print_r($err, true));
  curl_close($curl);

  if ($err) {
    sendRegistrationErrorNotification($err);
  } else {
    if (isset(json_decode($response)->error_code)) {
      sendRegistrationErrorNotification($response);
    }
  }
}

function getApiRegistrationPayloadFromEntry($entry, $renewal = false) {
  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 1 $entry: ' . print_r($entry, true));
  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 2 $renewal: ' . print_r($renewal, true));

  if ($renewal) {
    $values = array(
          'gender' => ucfirst(rgar($entry, 42)),
          'first_name' =>rgar($entry, 2),
          'last_name' => rgar($entry, 4),
          'email' => rgar($entry, 6),
          'telephone_1' => rgar($entry, 7),
          'fax_number' => rgar($entry, 27),
          'street_1' => ! empty(rgar($entry, 89))
            ? rgar($entry, 9) . ' - Unit ' . rgar($entry, 89)
            : rgar($entry, 9),
          'city' => rgar($entry, 11),
          'province' => rgar($entry, 12),
          'postal_code' => rgar($entry, 13),
          'status' => rgar($entry, 87),
          'referral_code' => rgar($entry, 23),
          'date_of_birth' => rgar($entry, 15),
          'establishment_name' => rgar($entry, 34),
          'establishment_type' => rgar($entry, 35),
          'mailing_street_1' => rgar($entry, 29),
          'mailing_city' => rgar($entry, 30),
          'mailing_province' => rgar($entry, 31),
          'mailing_postal_code' => rgar($entry, 32),
          'ship_to_doctor' => rgar($entry, 48) == 'practitioner' ? true : false,
          'caregiver_1_first_name' => rgar($entry, 62),
          'caregiver_1_last_name' => rgar($entry, 63),
          'caregiver_1_date_of_birth' => rgar($entry, 64),
          'caregiver_1_telephone' => rgar($entry, 65),
          'private_residence' => rgar($entry, 33) == 'private residence' ? true : false,
          'shipping_selection' => rgar($entry, 48),
          'archived' => rgar($entry, 19),
          'knumber' => rgar($entry, 95),
          'language_id' => rgar($entry, 94) == 'English' ? 'EN' : 'FR',
        );
  } else {
    $values = array(
        'date_of_birth' => rgar($entry, 15),
        'email' => rgar($entry, 6),
        'archived' => rgar($entry, 19),
        'enabled' => rgar($entry, 20),
        'gender' => ucfirst(rgar($entry, 42)),
        'first_name' =>rgar($entry, 2),
        'middle_name' =>rgar($entry, 3),
        'last_name' => rgar($entry, 4),
        'title' => rgar($entry, 1),
        'status' => rgar($entry, 21),
        'telephone_1' => rgar($entry, 7),
        'language_id' => rgar($entry, 94) == 'English' ? 'EN' : 'FR',
        'registration_attributes[gender]' => ucfirst(rgar($entry, 42)),
        'registration_attributes[first_name]' =>rgar($entry, 2),
        'registration_attributes[last_name]' => rgar($entry, 4),
        'registration_attributes[email]' => rgar($entry, 6),
        'registration_attributes[telephone_1]' => rgar($entry, 7),
        'registration_attributes[fax_number]' => rgar($entry, 27),
        'registration_attributes[street_1]' => ! empty(rgar($entry, 89))
            ? rgar($entry, 9) . ' - Unit ' . rgar($entry, 89)
            : rgar($entry, 9),
        'registration_attributes[city]' => rgar($entry, 11),
        'registration_attributes[province]' => rgar($entry, 12),
        'registration_attributes[postal_code]' => rgar($entry, 13),
        'registration_attributes[status]' => rgar($entry, 21),
        'registration_attributes[referral_code]' => rgar($entry, 23),
        'registration_attributes[date_of_birth]' => rgar($entry, 15),
        'registration_attributes[establishment_name]' => rgar($entry, 34),
        'registration_attributes[establishment_type]' => rgar($entry, 35),
        'registration_attributes[mailing_street_1]' => rgar($entry, 29),
        'registration_attributes[mailing_city]' => rgar($entry, 30),
        'registration_attributes[mailing_province]' => rgar($entry, 31),
        'registration_attributes[mailing_postal_code]' => rgar($entry, 32),
        'registration_attributes[ship_to_doctor]' => rgar($entry, 48) == 'practitioner' ? true : false,
        'registration_attributes[caregiver_1_first_name]' => rgar($entry, 62),
        'registration_attributes[caregiver_1_last_name]' => rgar($entry, 63),
        'registration_attributes[caregiver_1_date_of_birth]' => rgar($entry, 64),
        'registration_attributes[caregiver_1_telephone]' => rgar($entry, 65),
        'registration_attributes[private_residence]' => rgar($entry, 33) == 'private residence' ? true : false,
        'registration_attributes[shipping_selection]' => rgar($entry, 48),
        'registration_attributes[archived]' => rgar($entry, 19),
        'registration_attributes[knumber]' => rgar($entry, 95)
      );
  }

  GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . ' 3 $values: ' . print_r($values, true));
  return $values;
}
```

and i call the above in functions.php:

```
require_once(get_template_directory() . '/function-partials/gravity-forms-hooks-functions.php');
```

Comment: I'd try logging out the value of $response and it's decoded counterpart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error

There is a call to `sendRegistrationErrorNotification` inside `submitNewClientRegistration` which is only using `1` parameter.

This function requires `3` parameters, you need to send `$form` and `$entry` as the second and third params... inside `sendRegistrationErrorNotification` they are used   inside one of your strings so you couldn't just set the default values as you would still get an error.

Comment: Thanks very much. do you mean adding  $form, $entry inside  here:  if ($err) {
    sendRegistrationErrorNotification($err, $form, $entry);
  } else {
    if (isset(json_decode($response)->error_code)) {
      sendRegistrationErrorNotification($response);
    }
  }

Comment: You need to send something in the 2nd and 3rd or you'll get the 500 error. It would work if you sent it as `
    sendRegistrationErrorNotification($err, ['id' => 'id for form here'], ['id' => 'id for entry here']);` the values for ID you see there are used to create a link inside the error email your sending

Comment: OH MY GOD THANK YOU!! i spent all day!! thank you! so much!

Comment: Ha, no worries buddy.